# Preparing Huff model with data to use in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, modelling

I'm trying to find out about the notion of  potential of acessibility using the methods of Huff.

I´m using QGIS, with point data (with the variables that I would like to use) and polygons for Europe NUTS and LAU-2.

What I am looking for is the ability **to calculate areas of influence of the different points using the method of Huff.**

With QGIS, I cannot find tutorials or videos about how to make it work with the python console.

**So can there be any examples about to prepare a Huff model with data that we might use on QGIS?** *(I´ve already seen the posts relative to the Huff method on the forum but I do not know how to make it work properly with the python language)*

*PS: I have a  correct background with python programming, but I have problems with the way of making it work with GIS methods for this kind of theme.*

Comment: Searching this site for [Huff Model](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=huff+model) will provide you a few other references that you may find useful, but probably do not answer your question explicitly.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to try and focus it down to a single clear question, please?  At the moment it talks about using Huff in ArcGIS for Desktop and/or QGIS, looking for tutorials, and a Python error => too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: OK, I ll try to clarify the the questions. thank you for the rapid answer.

Comment: The screenshot looks like a [Reilly's Law of Retail Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reilly%27s_law_of_retail_gravitation) calculation.  It is not the same as a Huff model: [Huff has been very clear](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1003/files/huff.pdf) and insistent concerning the differences, in particular that some objective estimation of the probabilities is required in his model ("statistical verification").  When you edit this question, please clarify what kind of model you want and be more precise about what it might mean to "prepare" it.

Comment: Actually, I know that there are differences between the 2 models. But in the programm I showed with a picture, I could choose either the Reilly model or the Huff model. And what I showed was a Huff model. So I dont know now how to clarify better my question. Maybe an answer would take too much time to write on this forum, what I need is an example. Doesnt matter how exactly it is written, or what is your data, I would just like to see

Comment: Actually, I know that there are differences between the 2 models. But in the programm I showed with a picture, I could choose either the Reilly model or the Huff model. And what I showed was a Huff model. So I dont know now how to clarify better my question about it. Maybe an answer to it would take too much time to write on this forum. What I need is an example of how preparing these influence areas with point datas. Doesnt matter how exactly it is prepared, or what is your data, I would just like to see how it´s possible to prepare such a model technically, a sort of "short"tutorial. thanks

Comment: "It is not the same as a Huff model: Huff has been very clear and insistent concerning the differences, in particular that some objective estimation of the probabilities is required in his model ("statistical verification")" Thanks for the advice